# Only one annotation is showing

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

As you can see I have 3 different annotation classes. All 3 are identical except the name of the class. The only one showing up when I call for `Tree.getAnnotations()` is the annotation `@Element`.

```
    @Element(name = "node")
public class Tree<T> {

    private Tree<T>[] children = null;
    private T value;

    public Tree(T v, Tree<T>[] trees){
        children = trees;
        value = v;
    }

    public Tree(T v){
        value = v;
    }

    @SubElements(name = "subnodes")
    public Tree<T>[] getChildren(){
        return children;
    }

    @ElementField(name = "value")
    public T getValue(){
        return value;
    }

}
```

This is the annotation class:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Element {

    String name();

}
```

Comment: please to not link screenshots but post the code directly

Comment: Im sorry but i don't know how to do that

Comment: @AntonGustafsson Copy + Paste?

Comment: That's because the other 2 annotations are on methods, **not on the class**, don't you think?

Comment: there is a help section when creating a question: empty line and 4 white spaces...

Comment: Copy your code from your IDE and then paste it your question body and select whole code and click on the {}

Answer (score 1):

The class indeed has only one annotation. The other two belong to the class methods. To get to them you'd do something like:

```
Method getValue = Tree.class.getMethod("getValue"); //get the method
getValue.getAnnotations(); //get annotations, only ElementField in this case
```

The same for every other method.

Comment: So how should I access them? first time using this.

Comment: @AntonGustafsson Edited do add an example

Comment: @kaqqao thank you, i was having my hands full at work